# Is it possible to sort Specflow tests in Visual Studios 2012 Test Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, specflow, test-explorer

It looks like there is no sorting function for Specflow features in the test explorer of Visual Studio 2012. Does anyone have/know a workaround to ensure that tests are run in a particular order (since a test could be affected by the outcome/actions done in (a) previous test(s))?

The 'Ordered Test' functionality that is available in Visual Studio 2012 seems to be unavailable for Specflow features. A .orderedtest file you can create, doesn't recognize SpecFlow features as available tests.

Answer (score 3):

Having had this problem before I personally think that Ordered unit tests are a code smell. In theory each of our tests shouldn't be relying on any state that is created outside of its execution.

Consider it this way, if we are writing a normal unit test with mocked dependencies, then everything we need is created in our test method, before calling the SUT. As we roll up the testing scales we still need to ensure that things are in the correct state before calling our much larger SUT. For integration or system testing then, test packs will have been created and are ready to feed in, databases have been cleaned ready for the new input and even manual testers have been given their scripts of what to test.

When we consider tests at the SpecFlow level we need the same thing, the `Given`s still need to get everything in place before the `When` can be called.

However I personally have some integration level scenarios that read,

```
Given ...
And ...
When ...
Then ...
When ...
Then ...
Given ...
When ...
Then ...
And ...
```

In some ways these are synomynous with your ordered tests, the final `When` requires that all the previous `When`s have completed correctly. As such this breaks several of the tenets of *Unit Testing*, including the *Each test should only fail for one reason*, however I am personally ok with this, as my lower level unit tests handle provide the indicator for code issues.

Comment: I get what you're saying, and I agree that tests should be the least dependend on the outcome of other tests as possible. But sometimes there are tests that you want to be able to run seperatly (when some pre-conditions are already met), or be able to run together to test a complete chain of events. To prevent your testproject for getting cluttered with (partially) duplicated tests and such, I would like to be able to use all my 'small' tests and choose the order in which these tests are run.

Comment: +1 to @AlSki's post. All of your acceptance tests should be independent; mandating that they be run in a particular order will make them brittle and a nightmare to maintain (especially if you were to leave the project!). Check out the [FIRST](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2012-01/unit-tests-are-first) acronym for Unit Tests as they apply equally well to acceptance tests. If you have dependencies, use lots of Given, And, Whens as suggested in the post, but personally I'd avoid this and instead alter the granularity of your tests.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to "sort". You can use the *Group By* functionality in Test Explorer and you can create *Playlists* (Mark the tests -> right click -> Add to Playlist). As far as I know (but not used until now) *Ordered Tests* are also a way to sort tests.

Comment: I am aware of the 'Group By' and 'Playlist' functionality. But this isn't ensuring a particular order in which the tests will run. For instance, if I run only one test in a Playlist or Group, that test will jump to the top of the list and messing up the order in which they will be run if the whole Playlist or Group will be run the next time.

Comment: Ok, than you may have a look at Ordered Tests.

Comment: The Ordered Test functionality should be visible in the submenu when you right-click on a test in the Solution Explorer (according to MSDN). Though, I'm not seeing this functionality. I think because I'm using SpecFlow features. I've updated the question to clarify a bit.

Comment: Yes, right click -> add -> an then between unit test an generic test. Context Menu support seem to only available in test-projects. (+1 for interesting question)